# Correct way to guarantee thread safety when adding to a list using Parallel library

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, plinq

I loop over an array of connection strings and on each loop I extract some information and add to the list. Now, I want to use Parallel library to make it multithreaded, but I'm not sure if the library guarantees that writes to the list would be thread-safe or whether I need to use locking:

```
List<SomeType> list = new List<SomeType>();

settings.AsParallel().ForAll(setting => 
{
    list.AddRange(GetSomeArrayofSomeType(setting)); /// DO I NEED TO DO LOCKING HERE???
})
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just avoid this complexity in the first place, and pre-select the settings to be added to `list`?

Comment: I don't add settings to the list, I retrieve some array per setting, and add content of that array to the main list. Retrieval may be a long process, thus I need multithreading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write's to the list are indeed not safe for multithreaded writes.  You need to either use a `lock` to synchronize access or use a collection like `ConcurrentQueue` which is designed for multithreaded access.

Lock example (assuming `list` is a local of a method)

```
List<SomeType> list = new List<SomeType>();
settings.AsParallel().ForAll(setting => { 
  lock (list) {
    list.AddRange(GetSomeArrayofSomeType(setting)); 
  }
});
```

Or better yet use `SelectMany` instead of `ForEach`

```
var list = settings
  .AsParallel()
  .SelectMany(setting => GetSomeArrayOfSomeType(setting))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: It can also work well to have each task write to its own list (safe as there's only one thread seeing each list) and then combine them all in a final step. This can win because there's zero synchronisation needed for the first bunch of adds.

Comment: +1 for the SelectMany, the ForAll/lock sample should be avoided as it would introduce a lot of contention between worker threads.